# Watch mathematical C++ expression in Eclipse Debugger

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

I try to debug a C++ program with Eclipse CDT debugger.
But when I type a mathematical expression that contains a C math function such as *cos* or *fabs* in the *Expressions* window, I always obtain a wrong answer.

Edit: some examples:
[image]

Any idea?

Comment: tell us what you was trying to do? give  us some code

Comment: Some context, example input, code, or anything else would be helpful. The only thing I can think of from this is - your expression evaluates to `1`?.!

Comment: This question has severe formatting or content problems. This question is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

Comment: @zyboxinternational it is definitely likely to be improved via editing.

Comment: I don't understand your problem: my question is, however, clear: I just want to know why eclipse tells me that "fabs(-15) = 0" and not 15, and why "cos(3) = 1"...

Comment: @greg82 Are you sure the CDT debugger can **run** C code? because that is what you are asking him to do.

Comment: @UmNyobe Mmmh, I see, you're probably right. My old Java habits, probably... Thanks